# Assistance with for loops

Tags: java, loops

I had created a short algorithm to check for a value in an array and if it does not find the value, to output can't find value.

```
int [] array = {108, 10, 45, 67, 23, 29, 45, 48, 902, 2};
int in, out;
int index = 10;

for(out = 0; out < index; out++)
    if(array[out] == 200)
        break;
if(out == index)
    System.out.println("Coudld not find value");
```

It worked, as I had to go one value beyond to verify that the value was not in the array,  i realised that even though this for loop would output 0 - 9, it still worked for `out == index` (Which both have a value of 10). I realise that for loops, still increment to the value that terminates the loop, is this the reason this worked?

However I experimented with this and I got an array out of bounds error.

```
for(out = 0; out < index; out++)
    if(out == index)
        System.out.println(out);
```

Can you explain how this worked / how for loop works, if 10 is the value that terminates the loop, when loop is at `9 < index`, it still increments to 10 then `out = 10`, so does `out = 10`?

Comment: Please edit your title to explain the problem. It's currently unhelpful.

Comment: What code caused an array out of bounds error?

Comment: Ok, the second code does not cause a arrays out of bounds but it does not output, which is weird because in the first code when i where i have if(out == index) that outputs (because both out and index are 10).

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(out = 0;out < index;out++)
       if(out == index)
          System.out.println(out);
```

Is out of bounds because your array size is 10. That means it only has valid indices of 0 to 9. Your Index value is 10 in this case which is causing the out of bounds.

Try something like the following:

```
 int index = 9;
 for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
       if(i == index)
          System.out.println(array[i]);
```

This will ensure that you will never run into an OOB exception while looping through an array.

If you want to try and find something in your array:

```
 int toFind = 123;
 bool found = false;
 for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
 {
    if (array[i] == toFind)
    {
       found = true;
       break;
    }
 }
 if (found)
    sysout("Found");
 else
    sysout("Unable to find match");
```

Comment: But there's no array access in this loop.

Comment: @Eran I know but his error is obviously being caused by array access

Comment: When the loop’s condition is `out < index`, then the value `10` for `index` is **correct** as the loop’s body gets only executed as long as the variable `out` is *smaller* then `10` (hint: `array.length` also evaluates to `10`). Of course, it also implies that `if(out==index)` will never be true, but this should be obvious, even without arrays being involved, as a precondition of `out < index` precludes `out == index` in the loop body.

Comment: @Holger, yes exactly but if the element we are searching for is it in array[9] then i need a way output that we can not find the element, that is why i did out == index, so if out reaches 10, then that would show that the code didn't break. What i am confused about is, does the for loop register the terminating value, because the fact that out == index outputs, shows that out = 10?

Comment: @user283559 See edit. There are millions of ways to do searching/sorting with arrays and I can assure you that my way is no way near optimal. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user283559: `out` will be `10` *after* the loop, as that’s exactly the reason why a loop with the condition `out<10` terminates—the condition isn’t true anymore. But there’s no sense in testing for `out==10` *within* the loop’s body.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, your problem lies in realizing, that when you have a loop with a *condition*, that condition will always be `false`, when the loop ends normally, i.e. without a `break` and neither exceptionally.

But this is an intrinsic property of the loop, as the logic is *continue as long as the condition is true*. Thus, the loop won’t exit before the condition went `false`.

So when the condition is `variable < limit` and the loop hasn’t been stopped by a break, for subsequent statements after the loop, `variable >= limit` must be `true` (aside from floating point `NaN`s…). If `variable <= limit` was `true` to begin with and you’re incrementing the variable by at most one in each iteration, you can rely on `variable == limit` after the loop, unless it has terminated earlier, i.e. via `break`. This is what your first code example does.

*Inside* the loop’s body, the condition will always be `true`, assuming that you don’t modify the variables within the body. If you use the loop form `for(init; condition; update) body`, between two iterative executions of the body, the `update` action (the increment) gets executed, followed by a test of the `condition`. So, due to the evaluation of the `update` action, the condition might become `false`, the condition test will fail and the loop end.

---

The bottom line is, it’s not strange when the loop condition is `false` after the loop, it’s exactly what you asked for by specifying that the loop should keep running when the condition is `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Psudocode will be as follows for your `for loop`

```
int index =10;
int out =0;
::loop condition( out< index)  
{
   if(out == index)
          System.out.println(out);  
   ++out;
}
```

So at end of the loop your out has value 10 and it is equal to index

Comment: I don’t see how the pseudo code should make anything clearer as the original Java code. It’s also a mystery how the value `10` should get into your pseudo code, where everything is zero and the condition never true.